# Подскажите perfect-scrollbar ползунок!

Tags: angular

Использую в angular 7 библиотеку perfect-scrollbar. Использую через установленную версию (не директивой). Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы ползунок отображался всегда. В стандартном режиме ползунок появляется только при наведении. Пример кода:

```
    <perfect-scrollbar [config]= "{wheelPropagation:false}"  class="dropdown-list">
                <div *ngFor="let organisation of organisations" class="list-item"
                 (click)="loginIntoOrganisation(organisation.id)">
                <span class="organisation-name">
                 {{organisation.type == 0 ? organisation.shortTitle || organisation.title : organisation.fullTitle}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
```

Comment: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar/issues/626#issuecomment-315020540

Comment: [у них даже в документации все описано](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-make-the-scrollbars-always-visible)